# Is there is 'if integer' or similar statement in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to find a way to check if the result of a calculation in a formula is a whole number (integer) when divided.

I have had a look through the functions present in Crystal, but I cannot find anything along the lines of what I am looking for.

So far my code looks like the below

```
If {@recordnumber} / 12
//is an integer (not a decimal) | Here is where i am stuck as how to do 
this
Then opNo12 else
```

So ideally say the record number is 144, or any other multiple of 12, I want the formula to return opNo12.

If anyone can clear up if this is possible or alternatively point me in the right direction for a solution it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
if Trunc({@recordnumber}/12) <> ({@recordnumber}/12)
then
opNo12
else ""
```

Comment: Had to change the '<>' to a '=' but worked perfectly thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IF {@recordnumber} mod 12 = 0 Then opNo12 else ""

Comment: Sorry, I meant IF {@recordnumber} mod 12 = 0 Then opNo12 else ""